# What are some good J-E PC Dictionaries?

Tags: discussion

My first one was Microsoft Bookshelf with Kenkyusha's library of terms, and while I was really happy with it, a series of events has lead to me losing many of my electronic resources, some, like Microsoft Bookshelf, proving extremely difficult to replace.

What recommendations do you guys have?

Comment: One of the many [EPWING viewers](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPWING#.E6.A4.9C.E7.B4.A2.E3.82.BD.E3.83.95.E3.83.88.E3.82.A6.E3.82.A7.E3.82.A2) might do what you want, a lot of the Japanese dictionaries you can buy online are in EPWING format - they can be fairly expensive though

Comment: [This site](http://www.japaneselanguagetools.com/) has good Epwing dictionaries (both free and to buy).